# Align a figure in a specific position of a line?

Tags: floats

I want to align a figure on the left, but not at the very beginning of the line, but 20 points away from the beginning of the line so that it is at the same width as an itemization that I did in the previous chapter. Anyone know how to do it? My code is

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item F\"{u}r low-spin Komplexe
    \item \"{a}usserste s, p, d- Orbitale
\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \flushleft
        \includegraphics[width= 7 cm]{./VBtheory.png}
\end{figure}
\end{itemize}
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 3):

just use

```
\hspace*{20pt}{\includegraphics[width= 7 cm]{./VBtheory.png}
```

Note however the `figure` environment will allow it to float away from that indented list, for example to the top of the next page. It is intended to be used with a `\caption` so that you can refer to it wherever it is finally typeset.

If you want the image to be *part* of the item then do not set it as a figure, and it will automatically be set to the list margins:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item F\"{u}r low-spin Komplexe
    \item \"{a}usserste s, p, d- Orbitale

        \includegraphics[width= 7 cm]{./VBtheory.png}

\end{itemize}
```